# Database Error after updating from Webform 6.0.5 -> 6.1.0 in Drupal 9.2.7 (PHP 7.4.14)

Tags: webforms

After updating to Webform 6.1.0 the following error occurs:

> webform module 8626 - Issue #3240399: Move form #method, #action, and
> #attributes from properties to settings
>
> #8626 Fehlgeschlagen: Drupal\Component\Serialization\Exception\InvalidDataTypeException:
> Malformed inline YAML string at line 21. in
> Drupal\Component\Serialization\YamlSymfony::decode() (Zeile 40 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Serialization\YamlSymfony.php)

What can I do now?

Comment: This is best reported to the webform issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?categories=All  It would be even better if you can share the config export/YAML that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is a webform with invalid elements YAML that is only now being rejected by Drupal 9.x.

You can probably execute `drush repair` and it should detect the invalid elements YAML.

@see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3240399#comment-14277361

Comment: Or `drush webform:repair`.